# Real Projective Space - finding vector space of dimension n

Tags: vector-spaces

A: set of ALL lines in $R^{n+1}$.

**The question:**

Consider the  projection $f: A → RP^n$ sending every line to the parallel line through the origin. Describe  $f^{−1}(L_0)$ of an arbitrary point $L_0 ∈ RP^n$ and show that $f^{−1}(L_0)$ has a structure of a vector space (which does not depend on any choices) of dimension n.

**My answer:**

The pre-image of every point from RP^n (which is in fact a line) is a hyperplane of A , so a vector space of dimension n. The independence of choice is a consequence that RP^n is the quotient $R^{n+1} -  ${0}$ / $~ , where ~ denotes the equivalence relation  x ~ kx for some non negative k in $R^{n+1}$.

Please could readers criticise or confirm my answer is correct.

Many thanks, BT

Comment: How do you defined a hyperplane in $E$? I understand what you are doing, but I suspect part of the question is establishing a suitable isomorphism.

Comment: hmm. How about:

All lines in $R^{n+1}$ can be written as 

$c_{1}x_{1} + ...+ c_{n+1}x_{n+1} + d = 0$


map this to homogeneous coordinates: $[c_{1}: ...: c_{n+1}: d]$ 

Would that not suffice as an isomorphism?

Comment: A line can not be written that way, that is a hyperplane which is only a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$. A line can be characterised by  a direction and any point on the line.

Comment: Unfortunately, my reality is far more banal, I was referring to a pub on Solano Avenue in Albany, California. The photo was taken on Mount Shasta in Northern California.

Comment: My mistake. Thanks.

Comment: How about we describe the line in $R^{n+1}$ parametrically by

 $\vec{r(t)}$ = $t\vec{v} +\vec{r_{0}}$ so 

 $\vec{r(t)} = <x(t), y(t), z(t) >$ then use the map I did earlier.  ?

Comment: The pre image of $L_0$ is the set of all lines with direction $v$. If you let $H$ be the hyperplane perpendicular to $v$ passing through $0$, then each line intersects $H$ at some unique point. Define addition of two lines as the line passing through the addition of the intersection points, etc.